# I am a giant among ants

Tags: riddle, poetry

> I am a giant among ants, a nothing - yet something! - among man.
>
> I may be costly or inexpensive; my markings will tell you, done.
>
> In this grand year of 2019 my kind turns 41.
>
> We're made of a material not like a canyon or a can.
>
> I've got two arms, two hands, one head, two legs.
>
> That should sound familiar, I certainly think.
>
> So come, watch one of my movies with non-liquid drink!
>
> Just don't take my chair. It's small and covered with pegs.

And of course.......*Who am I?*

Comment: Sorry I've been away, guys! Had the flu. Still a little tired, but fever broke yesterday morning, so yay.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is

> a lego minifigure.

Explanation:

1. The giant among the ants

   > The lego is huge in the comparison of the ants. Though ants and some people may deem the Lego miniman as a nothing, one that does not worth anything at all, since it is not something that the ants can eat. But among humans, the mini Lego is a wonderful plaything, which makes a real significance in mankind. Take Legoland for instance.
2. It is costly or inexpensive

   > As seen above, some think this is worthless, so the Lego is costly to waste their money on something like that; some treasure it as a memory of their a childhood, so no matter the cost, is is a priceless thing, therefore buying a collection is inexpensive to them.
3. In the grand year of 2019 my kind turns 41

   > In year 1978, the Lego was created and was invited into the market. (Obviously, duh)
4. We are made of material not like canyon or can

   > It is not made from rocks and metal
5. > A Lego figure has 2 pairs of hands, legs, arms and a head
6. So come, watch one of my movies with non liquid drink.

   > There are 2 movies out already and both are bestsellers. Recently there is a new Lego movie 2 that's out now and in the cinemas. You can drink up the scene and story in the movie =non liquid drink
7. Don't take my chair. It's small and covered with pegs.

   > The Lego minifigure chair is as small as a fingernail. And the hard plastic pegs there can only fit the bottom of the Lego figures. It would be extremely uncomfortable to step on it, much less sit on it.

Comment: Thanks for the edit Rand al'Thor. @ladynoirminou great answer; don't forget the ">!" spoiler notation next time. Thanks!

Comment: nice one ;), +1!

Answer (score 10):

You are

> a Lego minifigure

First produced in 1978, thus turning 41 in 2019.

Comment: Would you mind adding a little more detail to your answer? Thanks!